# How to edit the php.ini file in Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Consider:

[image]

Now I am getting this error. How can I resolve this issue?

I found found some related issue, but that told me change *max-size* inside file *php.ini*, so how can I edit file *php.ini* (phpmyadmin-config)?

Importing into MySQL, the database size is above 100 MB. And the MySQL database size converts it into a ZIP file, and then import working, but it is not inserting all tables.

Comment: Why don't you import it directly from the terminal ? Something like that:
`zcat backup.sql.gz | mysql -u[username] -p[pswd] [db]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which OS or Apache server you're using right now.

If you are not aware of the `php.ini` file path then create one `info.php` file inside your *www/htdocs* folder and write the below line of code inside that file.

`<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>`

Execute the above file in your web browser. You will find the loaded `php.ini` configuration file path, like shown below.

[image]

Now go to the file path and increase the values of the below two variables as per your need.

```
upload_max_filesize=128M
post_max_size=128M
```

PS: Don't forget to restart your Apache server. :)

Comment: After creating info.php and run this url http://localhost/info.php i found path of php.ini. Thanks it help.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration file is located at the below path:

```
/etc/php/php_version/apache2/php.ini
```

Now increase the value of:

```
post_max_size = 150MB

upload_max_size = 150MB
```

Then restart the server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```